# How to close the browser opened by WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Browser is not closing once the app is launched

Once the browser opens from WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync and application launches, the browser still opens in background. If I click Android **mobile** back button it will open the browser which makes the user that its still signing in which is not right.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue about [WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync not closing Android browser](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1569) on the github.

And this problem was resolved in the Xamarin.Essential nuget package version 1.6. You can try to update the package in your project to the last version.